# I can't make Fallout 4 work

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-4, xbox-one

When I go to load my copy of Fallout 4 on my Xbox One it goes to the "please stand by" screen and then it loads for 1-2 minutes and then crashes. I am very confused and I can't find anyone else with the same problem. Note that I got the game new with a free copy of Fallout 3, so no mods. Another factor that could be that it's a new Xbox One S. Also don't direct me to xbox.com I've tried it and I didn't get the answer. Also note it's completely downloaded from the disk and there is no DLC or special edition or anything unusual.

Comment: Have you deleted the install from the HDD and tried to install it again? And Xbox wouldn't be the place to go for support , Bethesda.net or the main Fallout page would be.

Comment: I'm not the most technical person and I don't know what HDD is but I uninstalled and reinstalled my copy of Fallout 4 already. If you go see the common YouTube guides or Xbox One games won't work tutorials I have tried ALL of them. Also there is official guides on how to fix the problem on the Xbox website and I tried all of them. Didn't think Bethesda had a website though.

Comment: Ok I am looking at the game site and I found the support page and all I am finding is peoples answers to starting the game, I've tried everything these people are saying.

Comment: Is your disc damaged? Do other games work fine?

Comment: I can play watch dogs 2 so yeah the disk drive is fine, and NOTHING other than the drive has touched the disk.

Comment: My only other suggestion is exchange the disc and try that. Otherwise, it seems like a unique issue to you

Comment: is there a way to tell if it's bad other than the loading screen crashing?

Comment: Install on a different system with same disc. If it fails it's the disc. If it doesn't, it's your system.

Comment: I don't have another system other than PC. I have friends, but the only two in walking distance have 360's.

Comment: Then exchange your disc. If it works, it was the disc, if not...It's systemic

Comment: well the person who gave it to me mailed it from out of state.

Comment: ....Is it an original disk and not a copy?

Comment: It's an original disk not some sketchy thrift shop copy.

Comment: Then, you've got to figure out how to test the disc on a different system or a different copy on the same system to find what's wrong.

Comment: Ok thanks i'll try it, if it works on theirs I'll inform for anyone who has the same problem.

Comment: Ok I just got back from a friends house and I found out that the game worked on their console. So I'm testing it on my Xbox One S in a few minutes as soon as it reinstalls.

Comment: So I just found out that it's my Xbox One S that won't play the game. It's not the disk. I have one more idea and if it works than yay.

Comment: Well, assuming your friend had an Xbox one and that's not a 360 disc... It sounds like it's your system

Comment: My copy is an Xbox one version and my friend did have a normal Xbox one

Comment: Well, it's an issue in your console.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue just the other day, resolved mine by refreshing the dashboard.

Head to the dashboard, Hold RT + LT and press Y.

Comment: Did not realise this was months old. Hope you got it working!